# Stripe API: filter for Payout ID when I have destination ID (bank ID)

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm using python. I am trying to retrieve all payouts to a certain destination.

The code for retrieving everything is:

```
stripe.Payout.list(limit=3)
```

How do I add a parameter containing the destination ID? (Destination ID is in this form: ba_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured it out. This is not included in stripe API documentation. Just add a field like this:

```
stripe.Account.retrieve(destination = "ba_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

The only problem is this doesn't allow NOT filters. I can't do `!=`. It has to be `=` only. I haven't tried with `> or <`. Can anyone help me with this?